# Full Screen IAds is not closing

Tags: ios, fullscreen, iad

I am implementing IAds and it will appear successfully but when i close the ad it is closing the but the message is appearing that "You are connected to iAd"
how do i close this message
My Code is Here

```
-(void)showFullScreenAd {
    if (_requestingAd == NO) {
        _interstitial = [[ADInterstitialAd alloc] init];
        _interstitial.delegate = self;
        self.interstitialPresentationPolicy = ADInterstitialPresentationPolicyManual;
        NSLog(@"Ad Request");
        _requestingAd = YES;
    }

}




-(void)interstitialAd:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    _interstitial = nil;
    _requestingAd = NO;
    NSLog(@"Ad didFailWithERROR");
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}

-(void)interstitialAdDidLoad:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd {
    NSLog(@"Ad DidLOAD");
    if (interstitialAd != nil && _interstitial != nil && _requestingAd == YES) {
        [_interstitial presentInView:self.view];
        _requestingAd = NO;
    }
}

/*-(void)interstitialAdDidUnload:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd {
 _interstitial = nil;
 _requestingAd = NO;
 NSLog(@"Ad DidUNLOAD");
 }
 */
-(void)interstitialAdActionDidFinish:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd {
    _interstitial = nil;
    _requestingAd = NO;
    NSLog(@"Ad DidFINISH");
}
```

Comment: When you say "the message is appearing that "you are connected to iAd"" are you saying that a message appears in the log (NSLog) or an alert appears in the screen or the iAd keeps visible in the screen saying "you are connected to iAd"?

Comment: I have the same code as you and it works fine for me!

Comment: Alert Appearing on screen @CRoig

Comment: I don't see any line that shows an alert in the piece of code you posted. Try to find a line like [x show]; in your project (where x correspond to the alert object showing) and comment it. If you don't know the alert object name, I don't know how to remove it.

Comment: @CRoig Alert mean that the text is appearing on whole view such that behind the Ads which is currently showint

Comment: So it is not an alert, it is the actual interstitial. In my case, the did finish method is called when the x in the iAD is pressed. "Ad DidFinish" message is apperaring in the log when pressing the X?

Comment: @CRoig in my case the did finish method also call . and as you can see on my code i place  _interstitial = nil;
    _requestingAd = NO; but it is not disappearing

Comment: Try `[_interstitial presentFromViewController:self]` instead in didLoad method